# TYPO3 blog posts in one page

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, blogs, typoscript

I am quite new to TYPO3 and i am trying to build something which i am not sure how to do!

I have installed the T3G/blog extension.
On my website i have a "Blog" page, where i would like to show the blog posts like this (for each post):

- Post Title
- Post Date
- Full Post Content
- Post Author

I imagine i have to use a for loop to go through the blog posts available, but i can't find a way to make it work.

Right now i have something like this:

```
<div class="blog__content__left">
   <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>

   <div class="blog__post__title"></div>
   <div class="blog__post__date"></div>
   <div class="blog__post__content"></div>
   <div class="blog__post__author"></div>

</div>
```

The output of the debug is an array with my posts, but now my question is:

**how can i render the right information on the right place**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through all posts of a blog.

```
<f:for each="{blog.posts}" as="post">
    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
    <p>{post.content}</p>
</f:for>
```

There are so many tutorials about blog. Have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/3-BlogExample/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

### Debug

When you see the output in your debug, you can use the information in your template. Say your debug output sais the following:

```
 - Blog
  > Headline
  > Text
```

You can call these items in your template as `{blog.headline}` (for example).

### Using original files as base for your own template

- I suggest taking a look at the default templates provided. You can find these template in your `typo3/typo3conf/ext/{extension}/Resources/Private` Folder.
- Take a look at the tags being used! You can use these in your template.
- You should download the `Layouts, Partials and Template` folder, and upload these in your `fileadmin/{blogmodule}/` folder. Set the path in TypoScript, You'll probably find an example in the plugin documentation.