# Access the content of a DCE field outside of that DCE

Tags: typo3, blogs, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I use Fluid and the Typo3 blog extension *(T3G)*.
I created a DCE, and used it **inside a blog post page**.

The list of posts displayed in the blog mainpage shows the title, meta and abstract of the **blog post page** *(that's by default)*.

**I would like to add the content of a field from my DCE *(which is in my page)* to that preview. Is it possible to do that without PHP?**

Here is the default content of that preview partial from the blog extension: *[Resources\Private\Partials\List\Post.html](https://bitbucket.typo3.com/projects/EXT/repos/blog/browse/Resources/Private/Partials/List/Post.html)*

**I would like to add something like** `{field.mydcefield}` **into that default partial.**

I've been looking for two days now, but I'm struggling with DCE, Fluid, TCA, viewhelpers and that blog extension…

---

**EDIT:**

On [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892148/typo3-blog-posts-in-one-page#answer-46897194), it is said that one can use `{post.content}` to display content from a blog post page, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working…

I also had a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977856/typo3-get-thumbnail-for-menue-from-content-of-subpage), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344614/typo3-show-content-from-subpages-inlcuding-css-classes) without success… But maybe I'm just doing it wrong…

It would be fine if I could just display all content, I would then try and truncate it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, that is possible, but it might be a bit complicated.

your partial works in the context of a page(`post`): all variables are elements of that page.
You want data from a content element (CE) on this page.
So you have to get from page to CEs in that page.

That is not possible with standard fluid. But we have two solutions:

1. use an additional PHP-viewhelper, e.g. from `EXT:vhs`: [`content.get()`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/GetViewHelper.html)
2. use typoscript with the `cObject` viewhelper

For solution 2 you need further typoscript which gets your desired data, but you probably will not get it in single fluid-variables, but only a rendered result. (so you might do the rendering with (other) fluid.)
In this way you avoid PHP, but typoscript might be more complicated.

You would use a `CONTENT` object, select all tt_content records from the page (you need to use the page uid as an argument for the cObject VH) and then build your own rendering in the `renderObj` (here you can use a `fluidTemplate`)

If you find that the VH from `ext:VHS` is doing what you want, but you don't want to use the whole extension, you might copy this single VH to your own (site-)extension.

Comment: I have tried adding `<v:content.render column="0"></v:content.render>`, `<v:content.random.get column="0"></v:content.random.get>` and `<v:content.get column="0"></v:content.get>`. I only get "Array" rendered in the frontend in the best cases…

Comment: I also tried the second solution with a simple `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fluidText" />` and TS: `lib.fluidText = CONTENT
lib.fluidText {
   table = tt_content
   select.pidInList = this
   renderObj = < tt_content
}` which doesn't give me anything…

Comment: `renderObj = < tt_content` is not necessary as without explicit definition the default rendering for the record is used. more problematic is the select, which is very general ("all CEs from current page"? but maybe some automated restrictions interfere (sys_language, col_pos, ...)

Comment: I also found on [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892148/typo3-blog-posts-in-one-page), that you're supposed to be able to display the content using `{post.content}`.
But it doesn't work unfortunately and nothing from the content of the blog post page is being displayed.

Comment: Have you done a `<f:debug>`? that thread is old and the software might have changed meanwhile. You can work only with the data you have.

Comment: I did, but I get either a blank page or an error whenever I try to use `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`…

Comment: that sounds like a buggy installation. blank page means an internal error without revelation of interna, typical for production mode, in developer mode you should be able to see errors, which you need to solve. as a start you can call the install_tool and verify the installation.